Is it possible to say "messieurs et mesdames" same as "mesdames et messieurs", or not, why?
"Mesdames et messieurs" looks like idiom. Is it possible to change words places? Any literature examples?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_binomial

why i'm asking, because in russian it is possible to say both way, with a bit of difference. But russian phrase "господа и дамы" literally "messieurs et mesdames" is little bit elder and used rarely, then "дамы и господа" = "mesdames et messieurs". The last one looks like calque from french, because french was very popular in Russia that time.

Interesting indeed. (I don't know whether French considers this phrase irreversible, just wanted to add that term to aid in research)

Messieurs et mesdames is very rare and several occurences Google books find are either old or from foreign authors.

Mesdames et messieurs and the older Mesdames, mesdemoiselles, messieurs are very common.
They can be indeed considered as kind of irreversible binominal (resp. trinominal) as @LukeSawczak commented.
On the other hand, I have heard a lot of the colloquial M'sieurs-dames in casual contexts.

Thank you for answer and for comments too.

Peut être s'agit-il de la politesse, que de mettre des femmes avant des hommes

i'd checked dates of usage on russian literature texts corpus, is it possible to check same in french literature texts corpus? And i agree with you, looks like "mesdames/ladies first".

@άνθρωπος Indeed both can be said, mesdames et messieurs (or just mesdames, messieurs) is much more frequent because as said in this answer, having ladies fist was (still is?) considered more polite, just a matter of social conventions. This answer could be greatly improved by adding an ngram to evaluate frequency.

…excepting, @None, that n-grams don’t tell the whole story. For one thing they (obviously) are limited to the written language.
